How To Prove That The Absolute Convergence Of The One-Step Transition Matrix?
I am trying to prove that the n-step transition matrix in a Markov Chain satisfies the condition that the sum of each row is one (ie, each row is a valid probability distribution). I have done this using induction, which works if I assume absolute convergence (to apply Fubini's Theorem for infinite series).
In order to do this, I need to show that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P^{(1)}_{ik}P^{(1)}_{kj}$ is absolutely convergent. I don't know how to do this.
Edit: Would noting that the product $\sum P^{(1)}_{ik}P^{(1)}_{kj} \leq \sum P^{(1)}_{ik} = 1$ be enough to show this?

The fact that the sum of elements of each row is one follows directly from the axioms of probability, as it is the sume of the disjoint events the union of which is $\Omega$, the whole space, and its probability is $1$.

The fact that the elements are non-negative means we can already use Tonelli's theorem to interchange the sums.
